# Is it possible to output whole value content of pyspark structured streams?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am fetching pyspark stream data:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .getOrCreate()

raw_stream = spark \
    .readStream \
    .option("endpoint", conf.get('config', 'endpoint')) \
    .option("app.name", conf.get('config', 'app_name')) \
    .option("app.secret", conf.get('config', 'app_key')) \
    .option("dc", conf.get('config', 'dc')) \
    .option("source.topic", conf.get('config', 'topic')) \
    .option("group.name", conf.get('config', 'group')) \
    .option("source.value.binaryType", 'false') \
    .load()

raw_stream_str = raw_stream \
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

value_batch = raw_stream_str \
    .writeStream \
    .queryName("value_query") \
    .format("memory") \
    .start()

spark.sql("select * from value_query").show()
```

which output is as below:

```
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|{"message":"DGc6K...|
+--------------------+
```

How can I expand its content or print the whole line without this format?

Comment: do you mean you want to print the whole content in the column? set `truncate=False` within [`show()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.show.html)

Comment: @samkart Yes, I just wanted to check whole content of the value, that worked, thanks! I was wondering if there is another way to print out value content without using .show() and its output table-like format?

Comment: there's [`collect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.collect.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-collect) that will output list of rows.

Comment: @samkart thank you very much! My output data looks something like that:`[Row(value='{"message": "xxx", "source": "xxx", "instance": "xxx", "metrics": {"metric1": "xxx", "metric2": "xxx", ...}}')]` how can 1) I get it structured 2) extract the specific metric from nested key value dict?

Comment: it outputs a list and you can use its indices. in your case `[0][0]` should work and it'll result in the string. you can further use that string to convert it to a dict for use. see `json.loads`